# Slow website even though VPS is up and running

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address, vps

Sorry if this is a bit of a newbie question, but I am quite new to VPS and the *relatively* more complicated set up. I have a VPS set up, and every day or twice a day the site *loads* for a bout 10 minutes with no luck. Then when it comes back on line its fine after that. Upon logging on to Plesk, the server is up and running, very low CPU usage (0.10 and drops to 0.00 after a few minutes) and around 18% RAM usage.

The MySQLAdmin loads up fine.

So it seems the VPS is running fine.

Is there maybe another reason? The domain is with Daily.co.uk and the VPS is with LCN.com. Could there be another problem somewhere? On daily.co.uk, there are two nameservers set. ns0.etc*** and ns1.etc***. I did a tracert on windows cmd, this traced down to the server, with two timeouts.

I also tried a check on http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/ while the site was slow and this came back fine, except this: *Too few IPv4 name servers (1). Only one IPv4 name server was found for the zone. You should always have at least two IPv4 name servers for a zone to be able to handle transient connectivity problems.*

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried searching but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended diagnostic check for the issue you are experiencing is called a DIG.

On your Windows system, this check is not intrinsically available, but it can be downloaded from http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/

Once you have installed it, you'll want to run it from the command prompt with the following syntax:

C:> dig -insert your domain here- +trace

This will show you how DNS resolution is happening from your location to the requested end point. Chances are, the error you received is correct. Most DNS setups have several name servers to assign to your domain registration to allow the round-robining of delegated name servers in the event that one becomes unresponsive.

My personal recommendation would be to outsource the DNS to a managed provider. Doing so will increase the availability of the zone, and reduce latency.

Comment: Hi Carl. Thanks for your answer. So the DNS can be unresponsive even with having two (ns0. And ns1. )? The dns is as far as I know with a managed provider. It is with LCN.com who I have the VPS with. Should I maybe put the ip address of the website in as a 3rd nameserver?

Comment: Yes, DNS can be unresponsive with the two required name servers in your delegation. This can be due to unavailability or reliability issues with the DNS provider itself. Putting your IP address in as a name server is not the solution.